# Bad receiver type 'AVMediaType' in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am currently working on Camera View for a project which is already exist. My app is giving an error when I run the app. The main problem is that I am getting errors while running the project. The error is like mediaType with AVMediaTypeVideo. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY1iw.png).

[image]

I tried different options and I found that there is some changes in AVFoundation.

The next problem is related to the first since I am using the AVFoundation for my camera implementation on the top right corner I have a red error message which describes as in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsbZA.png).

[image]

It does not matter which language you have solution, it can be both Siwft and Objective-C.

If someone know anything about this issue please share it here and it would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post code instead of screenshot of code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code working fine for me.

```
AVCaptureConnection *connection = [_movieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
    if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]){
        NSLog(@"Media is Video type");
    }
}
```

Quit the Xcode and run again.

Comment: Hey @technerd Me and my team stuck hours on an issue very similar to what you've posted here. Any chance you can take a quick look? Ah, we are so frustrated. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235811/avassetwriter-avvideoexpectedsourceframeratekey-frame-rate-ignored/49236475#49236475